# Spark SQL - How to write custom encoder for a custom object with Map[String, Any] as a field of it?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a CSV as a DataFrame of my custom object type :

```
case class Geom(attributes: Map[String, Any])
```

I tried this :

```
import session.implicits._

implicit val mapEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Map[String, Any]]
implicit val geomEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[Geom]

val sparkSQLGeometryRDD = session.read
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("src\\main\\resources\\TexasPostCodes.txt")
  //.as[MyObjEncoded]//(encoder)
  .persist()

val columns = sparkSQLGeometryRDD.schema.fieldNames
//sparkSQLGeometryRDD.show()

val mappedDF = sparkSQLGeometryRDD
  .map(x => x.getValuesMap[Any](columns.toList))
  .map(x => Geom(x))
  .show
```

But it is throwing this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
```

Can someone please help me to find, what is wrong with my code ?

After moving case class and Encoders outside from the method, it is working fine.

```
object SpatialEncoders {
   implicit def MapEncoder: Encoder[Map[String, Any]]=     Encoders.kryo[Map[String, Any]]
   implicit def GeomEncoder: Encoder[Geom] = Encoders.kryo[Geom]
   implicit def SparkSQLGeometryEncoder: Encoder[SparkSQLGeometry]=      Encoders.kryo[SparkSQLGeometry]
}
```